# C - Warning ( passing 2 arguments .. )

Tags: c, arrays, warnings

I have 2 warnings with my program, how to fix it ?

1. `Warning: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'`
2. `Warning: passing argument 2 of 'copie' makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copie(int tableauOriginal[],int tableauCopie,int tailleTableau);

int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
    int tableauOriginal[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int tableauCopie[]= { };
    copie(tableauOriginal,tableauCopie,4);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("Case: %d\n", tableauCopie[i]);
    return 0;
}

void copie(int tableauOriginal[],int tableauCopie,int tailleTableau)
{

   int i ;
   for (i = 0; i < tailleTableau; i++)
      tableauCopie=tableauOriginal[i];
}
```

Comment: Because `tableauCopie` in `main` is an array, not an `int`.

Comment: tableauCopie is an array of integers, not an integer...

Comment: The error message is correct. The function expects an int and you give it a pointer. (which is mistreated in the function body, too, but that is a different issue)

Answer (score 2):

This is an error:

```
int tableauCopie[]= { };
```

If your compiler accepts it then it must be a compiler extension - probably creating a zero-sized array. Then you cause undefined behaviour when you write beyond its bounds with `copie`.

You have to specify the size:

```
int tableauCopie[4];
```

You could zero-initialize it with `= { 0 };` however that is unnecesary as `copie` is about to fill it in.

Of course, the `copie` function should accept the array as `int tableauCopie[]` - not a single int as you have currently; and its loop should have `tableauCopie[i] = tableauOriginal[i];`;

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
void copie(int tableauOriginal[],int tableauCopie[],int tailleTableau)
```

instead of

```
void copie(int tableauOriginal[],int tableauCopie,int tailleTableau)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared tableauCopie as an array. And in case of array only base address of array is passed so you should prototype your function as below.

void copie(int tableauOriginal[],int tableauCopie[],int tailleTableau);

or

void copie(int tableauOriginal[],int *tableauCopie,int tailleTableau);

Answer (score 0):

You should pass array name as pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void copie(int *tableauOriginal,int *tableauCopie,int tailleTableau);

int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
    int tableauOriginal[4]={1,2,3,4};
    int tableauCopie[4]= {0};
    copie(tableauOriginal,tableauCopie,4);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("Case: %d\n", tableauCopie[i]);
    return 0;
}

void copie(int *tableauOriginal,int *tableauCopie,int tailleTableau)
{
   int i ;
   for (i = 0; i < tailleTableau; i++)
      tableauCopie[i]=tableauOriginal[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ! But can you explain me ? please

Comment: There is no problem with passing arrays with brackets. You should then explain why using the pointer notation over the bracket one.

Comment: @user3521273: In C/C++, the array name is used as a pointer. Through the pointer, you can modify the content in the memory.

Comment: @user3521273 If it helped you solve your problem, consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

should be as below as tableauCopie is an array.

void copie(int tableauOriginal[], int tableauCopie[], int tailleTableau)
  {

```
  int i ;
  for (i = 0; i < tailleTableau; i++)
    tableauCopie[i] = tableauOriginal[i];
```

}